# Convergence in $L^1$ problem.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**: Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R},~\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. For any $h \in \mathbb{R}$, define $f_h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f_h(x) = f(x - h)$. Prove that:
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \|f - f_h\|_{L^1} = 0.$$

**My attempt**: So, I know that given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a continuous function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support such that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f - g|d\mu < \epsilon.$$
We can then use the inequality $|f - f_h| \leq |f - g| + |g - g_h| + |g_h - f_h|$ to reduce the problem to the *continuous* case, so to speak, since the integral of the first and last terms will be $< \epsilon$. But now I'm stuck trying to show that
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \|g - g_h\|_{L^1} = 0.$$
I tried taking a sequence $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$ and considering $g_n := g_{h_n}$, but I don't have monotonicity and the convergence doesn't seem to be dominated either, so I don't know what to do.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It follows from the uniform continuity of $g$ on its support. For a detailed proof, see Rudin, *Real and complex analysis*, Theorem 9.4. It also appears on Brezis' book (at least in the italian edition), but the main step of the proof is left to the reader!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By your construction, $g$ is continuous and compactly supported.
Let $K$ be the support of $g$, and let $K_h=K\cup (h+K)$.
Then we have
$$
\int|g(x)-g(x-h)|\,\mathrm{d}x\leq |K_h|\|g-g_h\|_{L^\infty(K_h)}.
$$
For all $h>0$ sufficiently small we have $K_h\subset K_1$, and you can invoke uniform continuity of $g$.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the fact that $f_h$ is in $L^1$ by translation invariance and the fact that $|f-f_h|\leq|f|+|f_h|$.  So now you have a function $g_n=|f-f_h|$ which converges to 0 and is bounded by an integrable function.

Comment: What is the integrable function that bounds $g_h$?

Comment: What is a dominant function for $|f_h|$, independent of $h$? Of course it is a multiple of $|f|$ when $f$ is continuous, but then your suggestion reduces to the continuous case.

Comment: I believe $|f|+|f_h|$ is integrable.

Comment: But $|f_h|$ is not fixed..